# Get Dotfuscated settings from framework 3.5 into framework 4.5?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I was using `Dotfuscator` `Version: 4.2.5000.27915` in my Visual Studio Dot NET framework 3.5. I am having huge amount of settings based on this version of Dotfuscator.

Now, There is a compulsion need for me to move on framework 4.5. But the issue here is that this version of Dotfuscator does not support in framework 4.5.

Is there any way to get my settings in framework 4.5 without losing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dotfuscator operates on [Dotfuscator config files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42698046/2137382), which store settings about an obfuscation build.
You should be able to open your config files with newer versions of Dotfuscator and preserve your obfuscation configuration.

I should mention that Dotfuscator version `4.2.5000` was released in two editions: the free Community Edition (CE) included with Visual Studio 2008, and the fully-supported Professional Edition.
The newer versions of Community Edition are versioned at `5.x`, while the Professional Edition remains versioned at `4.x`, but both should be backward compatible with config files from `4.2`.
You can always get the latest versions of Dotfuscator from [the Dotfuscator Downloads page on PreEmptive's website](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/downloads).

Note that if you are using Community Edition, the latest releases do not support Visual Studio 2012 and 2013, as mentioned in the question tags.
While these releases of Visual Studio include older versions of Community Edition, I strongly discourage using them, because they don't have [the latest updates](https://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support/dotfuscator-ce-change-log) to address current reverse engineering threats.
You should either use the latest Community Edition with a newer version of Visual Studio, or the latest Professional Edition (which is installed separately from Visual Studio, and therefore can be used with older Visual Studio versions).

*Disclaimer: I work for PreEmptive Solutions, on the Dotfuscator team*.