# PreEmptive Protection Dotfuscator Map.Xml and Dotfuscator1.Xml for winform executable

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015, executable, setup-project, dotfuscator

I'm using `PreEmptive Protection Dotfuscator` for `winform` executable `.exe` file.

Do I have to add `Map.Xml` and `Dotfuscator1.Xml` to `Setup Project` with other `Dependencies` to locate it in  `Program Files/MyApp` directory, or it is no needed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PreEmptive Protection Dotfuscator exe files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684604/preemptive-protection-dotfuscator-exe-files)

Comment: But to emphasize, **DO NOT PUT THESE FILES IN YOUR INSTALLER** and do not distribute them with your app.

Comment: @Joe Sewell Hello, but do I have to add it with creating of `setup.exe` in `Setup Project`, at the stage of adding of obfuscated `.exe` instead of compiled  `.exe` in `Debug` folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I am a developer on Dotfuscator and am answering this as part of my job.)*

No, after Dotfuscator has run and created a protected/obfuscated `.exe` file, you typically do not need to involve the `Map.xml` or `Dotfuscator1.xml` files in any later step of your build process. Your protected `.exe` file will be able to run without them, and they are not needed when building your setup executable.

In fact, these files contain sensitive information that could be used to undo parts of the obfuscation. **Do not add these files to an installer project, packaging project, or anything that could potentially leave your organization.** For details, including how to handle these files as part of your development process, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42698046/2137382).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will take the opportunity to ask. In `C#` `winfrom` application I'm using `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`, I have connection string which contains unsaved data `MyServer`, `MyDatabase`, `MyUser`, `MyPassword`, for example   `string conStr = "SERVER= MyServer;PORT=3306;DATABASE=MyDatabase;UID=MyUser;PASSWORD=MyPassword;"`. I'm using `JetBrains dotPeek` to check decompilation, in result this data is available, even if code is obfuscated. Do I have any option for this, in PreEmptive Protection Dotfuscator free version included to my VS15?

Comment: @ViktorArv String encryption is not available in the free Community Edition included with Visual Studio. You can request a free evaluation of Professional Edition, which does have this feature, from PreEmptive's [web site](https://www.preemptive.com/my-account/evaluations?view=evaluations&getevalbutton=1).